# Integration Services Throws an Error Reading Access 2007 Table

Tags: ms-access, ssis

[Participant Table [1994]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "I:\My Documents\Flamm Consulting\Migrations.accdb" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Frankly, I'm confused about how SSIS should connect to Access 2007 - the UI just isn't very friendly - there's no file browser, for example. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my install - missing drivers, etc.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong connection string, i.e., using Jet 4 instead of the ACE connection string.

Comment: As to whoever voted this to be a SuperUser question, are you crazy? What end users are using SSIS? Looks like somebody has the ludicrous idea that any question with the ms-access tag doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Two guesses - first, you're attempting to run this package on a 64-bit server, which isn't going to work without a tweak.  Second, you don't have the drivers installed.

For info on the first, try here: [SSIS in 32- and 64-bits](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2009/10/quick-reference-ssis-in-32-and-64-bits.html).
For info on the second, try here: [Interacting with Office in SSIS](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2010/01/quick-reference-interacting-with-office.html).

Comment: Todd,

Thanks for the links - I'm running this package in BIDS, and the Run64BitRuntime flag did the trick (setting it to False, of course).

Eric

Answer (score 0):

SET RUN 64 to False from the project properties.